# Installing MySQL in Solaris

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I am trying to install MySQL 5.5 on Solaris 10.
I executed the code **useradd -r -g mysql mysql** where a group called mysql is already created using groupadd command.

I get the following error :
UX: useradd: ERROR: invalid syntax.

Is -r option not availablr on Solaris ?
Am I missing something.
I am newbie to Soalris.

Comment: Welcome to the land of UNIX (and Solaris). The commands, while named the same, sometimes have different switches/arguments. Just use `man` command to lookup information.

Answer (score 1):

just use:

```
useradd -g mysql mysql
```